# JSP/Servlet Design Pattern Suggestions for Web Application

Tags: java, jsp, design-patterns, web-frameworks

I am working within a RESTful Web Framework that is natively script (JSP) based. The Framework has a routing mechanism that automatically sets a number Request attributes, which are then available in the JSPs (One of the attributes being a "Model" of the requested resource; which is basically just a HashMap).

The issue is 90% of the time, some amount of logic is required to be added to the JSP, be it more complex domain logic, retrieving other resource data (other Models), or scrubbing data for output.

I am looking at various establish web application design patterns for extracting domain logic out of the JSP, and keeping the JSP as logic-less as possible.

A few things to note:

1. Within the system im working in, the Model (the data pull from the database) is provided but the Framework (the previously mentioned HashMap); I could create my own Model wrappers around this data, but it's probably unnecessary.
2. JSP/Scripts are the end points for Requests - If I use a pattern that uses a Presenter/Controller-type object that returns a View bean (ViewModel?) which contains all the data the view will use, I will need to have a line in the JSP which calls the Presenter/Controller and instantiates the View bean.

Currently I've created a Presenter POJO for each Module (script), which has access to the Model (again, the Framework sets this as a Request attr), and simply instantiate it at the top of the JSP, and use it more or less like a bean.

If I understand it, correctly, I believe i've implemented the Presentation Model design pattern. [1]

Ex.

JSP looks like:

```
<% DemoPresenter demo = new DemoPresenter(request) %>
<%= demo.getTitle() %>
- or add it to pageContext to use w JSTL/EL -
<c:set var="demo" value="new DemoPresenter(request)"/>
${demo.title}
```

And the "Presenter/Controller" looks like:

```
public class DemoPresenter extends BasePresenter { 

   private String title; 

   public DemoPresenter(HttpServletRequest request) { 
       FrameworkModel model = request.getAttribute("frameworkProvidedResourceModel");
       this.title = model.get("title").toUpperCase() + "!!!";
   } 

   public getTitle() { return this.title; } 
}
```

Any thoughts on using the Presenter obj directly in the JSP/Script, vs having it return a "logic-less" ViewModel bean that the Presenter populates w/ data? The advantage to this is I could have a single Presenter managed various "Views" of the same resource (such as Show-view, Edit-view, Summary-view, etc.) - Below is an example of how i could get various view models.

/blog/posts/1/show -> executes JSP which gets its ViewModel like so:

```
<% DemoDefaultViewModel default = new DemoPresenter(request).getViewModel(DemoDefaultViewModel.class); %>
```

/blog/posts/1/edit ->executes a JSP which gets its ViewModel like so:

```
<% DemoEditViewModel edit = new DemoPresenter(request).getViewModel(DemoEditViewModel.class); %>
```

I would like to keep a simple solution without too many extraneous pieces. I also can't get too fancy as I am working within a strict predefined framework - I just want to figure out a good way to move all my domain logic out of the JSP into more reusable, testable Java classes.

[1] http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out struts.
I must admit to only having used the older version but the 'front controller' servlet idea seems to be what you're after . It is a special servlet to run common code and route requests.
It also has actions which can be tested outside of the web container.

The day I moved from pure JSP to struts was one of the best days of my web development life! The project started to feel organised and much easier to manage.

Comment: "The day I moved from pure JSP to struts was one of the best days of my web development life!". - I respect your experience man! I bet you did that more than ten years ago. Otherwise moving to Struts would be moving to the Stone Age. In 2012 you should move away  from JSP for sure, but not to Struts but to HybridJava!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of MVC frameworks. For example Struts uses a front controller servlet to dispatch requests to a class (controller) depending on the resource used. The class processes the request and sends the result to the view (typically a jsp). The model is any class that represents your data. FYI, a Map is not a framework. Representing your data as a MAP only, will work, but is ugly and hard to maintain.

Without knowing your strict framework, generally accepted good practice would be to keep your business logic centralised and independent of any framework. Use your framework for plumbing only. Get your controller to mediate between your presentation and business logic, again this is just plumbing. Put your display data in the right scope (almost always the request scope) so you dont have to have scriptlets as in your example.

Comment: Unfortunately I am tied to this framework, for better or worse. I also know a map is not a framework, I was simply noting how the framework natively exposes te data to the view.

Comment: Which frameworks it? Bad luck if it's a homegrown one! Where does the framework intervene? By your description, it is at least in the data layer. If its only there, then you could look at using front end layer framework like struts, jsf, wicket or any of the many out there. Personally I'd look to turn my maps into domain objects as quickly as possible. Both from a development effort and also from a code perspective. Meaning the instance the map is available in code, turn it into something meaningful.